# StageWebView, trouble finding any good documentation from Adobe

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-builder

Does anyone have a *good* link to a very *simple* example of how to set up a working StageWebView?

It's so simple and well documented for iOS, I can't seem to find anything helpful for developing with Adobe Flash Builder.

I have found this code:

```
        import spark.components.Image;
        import spark.events.ViewNavigatorEvent;

        public var webView:StageWebView = new StageWebView(); 

        public function init():void 
        { 
            webView.stage = this.stage;
            webView.viewPort = new Rectangle( 0, 50, stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight );
            webView.loadURL("http://www.google.com");  
        }

        protected function logoutHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            NativeApplication.nativeApplication.exit(); 
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>
```

How do I then actually attach this to an element that will appear on the screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you're referencing a Flex or pure ActionScript project within Flash Builder; however, something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
                       xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
                       xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
                       addedToStage="addedToStageHandler(event)">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;

            protected var stageWebView:StageWebView;

            protected function addedToStageHandler(event:Event):void
            {
                stageWebView = new StageWebView();
                stageWebView.viewPort = new Rectangle(0, 0, stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight);
                stageWebView.stage = stage;
                stageWebView.loadURL("http://maps.google.com/");
            }

            override protected function updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number):void
            {
                super.updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);

                if (stageWebView)
                    stageWebView.viewPort = new Rectangle(0, 0, unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
</s:WindowedApplication>
```

For pure ActionScript, `addedToStage` would be the same implementation but you'd handle resize via your own handler lifecycle such as `Event.RESIZE`.

References

- [StageWebView ActionScript 3.0 Reference for the Adobe Flash Platform](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/StageWebView.html)
- [Using the StageWebView class (Adobe Developer Connection)](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/quick_start_as/quickstarts/qs_using_stage_web_view.html)
- [Displaying HTML content in mobile apps](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS901d38e593cd1bac3ef1d28412ac57b094b-8000.html)
- [Create a basic web browser (Adobe Cookbooks)](http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Create_a_basic_web_browser_with_StageWebView-18850.html)
- [StageWebView differences between platforms](http://helpx.adobe.com/air/kb/stagewebview-differences-platforms-air-sdk.html)

Comment: Thank you for your response, and the references!  I have had a horrible time finding good references for developing in flash builder.

Answer (score 0):

You can use mx ui component in your class & in this component you can add any stagewebview.
use Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE listener, to make sure that stage variable has been prepared. 
Than you can add into stage variable of mx ui component as using addChild function.

```
<mx:UIComponent x="0" y="0" width="958" height="567" id="component_UI"/>
component_UI.stage.addChild(Your Stagewebview object)
```

Comment: Thank you.  You response was helpful.  I used both your response and Jason's below to fix my problem.